# How to Schedule multiple jobs with only one trigger with Quartz.net

Tags: c#, scheduling, quartz.net, job-scheduling

I want to add some jobs to a scheduler in Quartz.Net. Then, I only want to add one trigger for all jobs and run then only with one trigger.

Comment: What's stopping you from doing exactly that?

Comment: I want something like that (pseudocode): 
schedular.AddJob(job1, trigger) - 
schedular.AddJob(job2, trigger) - 
schedular.Start(); 
That's it.

Comment: please give me a sample

Comment: You just did. I honestly do not understand your question. You obviously already know how to do it.

Comment: I'll try it, thanks